# Move Files To Directories Based on File Name

Tags: bash

I have files that download to one directory (`/media/Downloads/Complete/Movies`) but need a bash script that moves them to the destination directory based on file name (`/media/Movies_A` & `/media/Movies_B`)

Example:

```
/media/Downloads/Complete/Movies/Frozen.mkv ---> /media/Movies_A/

Movies with titles A-M go to /media/Movies_A
Movies with titles N-Z go to /media/Movies_B
```

I also need it to ignore "the" (the land before time) would go to `/media/Movies_A/The Land Before Time`.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Sure but do you not also want movies that start with "A {something} to the directory the same as with "The "?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably enough:

```
cp /media/Downloads/Complete/Movies/[tT]he[\ .][A-Ma-m]* /media/Movies_A/ 
cp /media/Downloads/Complete/Movies/[tT]he[\ .][N-Zn-z]* /media/Movies_B/
cp /media/Downloads/Complete/Movies/[A-Ma-m]* /media/Movies_A/ 
cp /media/Downloads/Complete/Movies/[N-Zn-z]* /media/Movies_B/
```

I used `cp` so you can redo it as many times as you like.

The [] in the command make it a collection of letters. The \ is to escape the space. The `[\ .]` matches a space or a `.` so you will also copy `The land` and `the.land` and similar names correctly.

Tip: If you drop the 1st [ and type a t or T and then press TAB (twice?) it will show you all  the files that are included. If you then do a backspace and add the [ again you know you are on the right track.

Comment: so if i want to move the files, do i just change cp to mv?  Also, if i wanted to make this a bash script, do i just add #!/bin/bash at the top and save as filename.sh and put it in cron folder?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. No need for bash. Just copy the commands to a file and make it executable. I tend to use /etc/crontab :)

Comment: Souldn't it be `[A-M].*`?

Comment: Doubt it :) It would mean filenames with 1 letter from A to M and then a dot and then 0 or more characters. If you just use the commands that is.

Comment: @ToDo: You're confusing [globbing](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/glob.7.html) with regular expressions.

Comment: what if i wanted to check if the source folder had anything to copy first? I can not get the following to work:  http://pastebin.com/a1Y7NA4R

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out myself: http://pastebin.com/gJtS69m6 for those who are interested

Comment: Note that `[A-M]` will typically be equivalent to something like `[AaBbCc...LlM]` in most locales, depending on how the given language sorts things lexicographically. May also include non-ascii letters the current language happens to sort in between there. In this case, this is probably ok, but may be worth noting. To have it mean `[ABCDEFGHIJKLM]`, set `LC_COLLATE=C` (or since bash 4.3 there's also: `shopt -s globasciiranges`). Don't you just love locales? :)